# ImportError cannot import name 'dump_options_header'

Tags: python-3.5, odoo-11

whene i run my application odoo in `eclipse` i got this error

`>from werkzeug.http import dump_options_header, dump_header, generate_etag, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_options_header'

> from werkzeug.http import dump_options_header, dump_header, generate_etag, \
>       quote_header_value, parse_set_header, unquote_etag, quote_etag, \
>       parse_options_header, http_date, is_byte_range_valid
>   from werkzeug import exceptions`

Answer (score 0):

what is your version of Werkzeug ?

Find the version with one of this commands

```
pip list
```

if you have install flask

```
flask.__version__
pip freeze | grep Flask
flask --version
```

If it is 1.0.0 try your after Werkzeug downgrade

```
pip install Werkzeug==0.16.1
```